# Can I move objects using JavaScript/jQuery in real time to create an animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a project that stores a series of moves in PHP.
For example, I have a 100x100 grid with two boxes in it. The PHP code creates the coordinates that the boxes move to and each box can do multiple moves per turn.

I would like to animate the moves so users could see the boxes move in real time. To do this, I created a JS array of the coordinates using PHP, then created a jQuery script to iterate through the array and move the objects one at a time, using a setTimeout to control the speed of the changes.

However, this seems to just process all the moves and then only output the final locations. Firefox works a bit better than Chrome, but the setTimeout just seems to delay the final result being shown, rather than delaying each step.

Is there a way to show each move in real time?

Here is my JS:

```
var locations = {};
locations[0] = { "box":"box1" , "left":"52" , "top":"94" };
locations[1] = { "box": "box2" , "left":"0" , "top":"18" };
locations[2] = { "box": "box1" , "left":"29" , "top":"34" };
...

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.each(locations,function(step,details){
        setTimeout(processMove,1000,step,details);
    });
});
function processMove(step,details){
    var box = $('#' + details['box']);
    box.css("left",details['left'] + 'px');
    box.css("top",details['top'] + 'px');
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: There is a whole section in the api for [Effects](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/). A simple google search for `jQuery animation` would have turned up many many results. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: The question is not about jQuery animation effects.

Comment: Can sure be interpreted that way since it is not very clear what *"show each move in real time"* really means. Not to mention ... ***"I would like to animate the moves"***

Comment: Not if you read the question.

Comment: A lesson in being clear whan you explain your issues as per [ask]

Comment: Thank you for your unhelpful comments, but it was clear enough to get the answer I required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work with your setup but I would recommend using array `locations` rather than object.

```js
var locations = {};
locations[0] = { "box":"box1" , "left":"52" , "top":"94" };
locations[1] = { "box": "box2" , "left":"0" , "top":"18" };
locations[2] = { "box": "box1" , "left":"29" , "top":"34" };var cnt = 0;
    
var handle = setInterval( function() {
    //processMove(locations[cnt]);
    console.log(locations[cnt++]);
    if (cnt > Object.keys(locations).length - 1) {
        clearInterval(handle);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can. There is a whole API for this in jQuery: 
http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: Thank you, but jQuery animate would not work for what I need.